# Array input after pressing enter becoming 0

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main() {
        int start_time[3];
        int final_time[3];

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<3; i++)
            cin >> start_time[i];

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            cin >> final_time[i];

        int a[10];
        for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
            a[i]=0;

        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            cout << start_time[i] << " " << final_time[i] << endl;
        }



    }
```

If I give the following input:

```
23 53 09
23 53 10
```

We see that the output is:

```
23 0
53 53 
9 10
```

Why is it taking the starting input of final_time equal to 0 after I press enter?

How do I solve this?

Comment: I just ran the same code you have provided in my local machine. I am getting the expected answer as output with no errors. Could you please recheck the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int a[10];
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        a[i]=0;
```

In this part, you are writing a `0` into `a[10]`. But `a[10]` does not exist. `a[]` only has space for 10 integers, indexed 0 to 9. So you are writing a zero to somewhere in memory, and you overwrote your `final_time[0]` by chance. Could have been something else or could have crashed your program, too.

Fix this by correcting your loop to `for(i=0;i<10;i++)` like your other loops.

Writing to an array out of it's allocated bounds is undefined behavior in C++. that basically means it's not defined in the standard and each compiler vendor will have to make something up for their product on what should happen if you do this. So it's rather random and therefor bad (tm). You may get a different behavior when you switch compilers, you may even get a different behavior when you restart your program. In your case, your compiler vendor (like many others) decided that they will just not check if the developer was correct. They just write that zero to the space in memory that `a[10]` *would* have been at, had it existed. But it did not. And by plain chance there was another variable at that spot in memory. So that one had it's value overwritten by the zero.

Comment: this fixed my error but  how does the bottom loop affect the upper loop? and
if i am going to access a[10] and it is not present i should get a segmentation fault right since i am accessing a memory which has not been allocated ?

Comment: @BandrevuAkhil Edited for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking a undefined behaviour by out of bound indexing for array `a`

The for loop

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        ~~~
```

should use `i < 10` to index from 0 to 9 for 10 elements

Comment: this fixed my error but  how does the bottom loop affect the upper loop? and
if i am going to access a[10] and it is not present i should get a segmentation fault right since i am accessing a memory which has not been allocated ?

Comment: @BandrevuAkhil Memory is allocated in larger units than just the size of a single array. Accessing outside an array won't always get a fault, it will just access the memory assigned to some other variable or used by the implementation.